Providing dynamically created pydantic model as type annotation to function without mypy errors
I am using a pluggable architecture which registers pydantic models with a central registry on startup.
These models are then added to an existing model as a Union field dynamically.
This resulting class is then used by a framework we use (dagster) to provide yaml configuration in a UI.
The issue I am having is that dagster uses the type annotation of an argument called config on decorated functions to register and use these config classes. I am using a factory function to create these functions in the following way:
# assets.py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from dagster import asset, AssetsDefinition

# Factory function to dynamically create an asset 
def create_asset(identifier: str, config_class: Type[BaseModel]) -> AssetsDefinition:

    # Library code wrapped in framework stuff
    @asset(key=identifier)
    def _inner(config: config_class) -> None:
        ...
    return __inner


# Library entrypoint code
# Register all plugins
plugin_configs: List[BaseModel] = register_plugins()

class MyBase(BaseModel):
    configs: Any # will be replaced with a Union[<registed config classes>] field

config_class: MyBase = create_updated_model(MyBase, plugin_configs)

# Load a list of ids to create assets for in config
my_list_of_ids: List[str] = load_asset_ids()

assets = [create_asset(id, config_class) for id in my_list_of_ids]

When I run mypy on this I will get:
error: Variable "assets.config_class" is not valid as a type  [valid-type]

If the framework wasn't reliant on the type annotation for actually using the config class I could just create a protocol in the asset module for type hinting / IDE help to avoid this.
My fundamental understanding of the problem here is shaky at best after reading this: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#variables-vs-type-aliases
For now I am ignoring this error via # type: ignore but I want to know if this is solvable in a way that keeps the framework happy (that needs the actual dynamically generated class as the annotation) and mypy happy?
Ran mypy, expected no errors but got  Variable asset.config_class is not valid as a type  [valid-type]
